# automatically pair up peer to peer connections using socket.io, socket.io-p2p, socket.io-p2p-server

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io, webrtc, p2p

I am attempting to hook up a small game with WebSockets. I am using socket.io, socket.io-p2p, and socket.io-p2p-server. I want users to be automatically paired up against any connected player who doesn't have a partner. I want users to only be connected in pairs.

So far simply following the docs I can only get clients to connect using just socket.io. When I attempt to use socket.io-p2p and socket.io-p2p-server I can sometimes get users to connect and other times I get error messages on the screen like

"Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined"

Someone opened an issue for this problem on the repo and didn't get a response and never got a response

https://github.com/tomcartwrightuk/socket.io-p2p-server/issues/5

I don't know if socket.io-p2p-server is broken or if I am just missing something. Further more socket.io-p2p-server has not been touched much since march.

So my main questions are:

- Is socket.io-p2p-server still alive?
- Is there a better implementation I can use for these abstractions?
- Would writing my own logic instead of using socket.io-p2p-server be worth it?

client side code

```
    import P2P from 'socket.io-p2p'
    import io from 'socket.io-client'

    const socket = io()
    const p2pSocket = new P2P(socket, null, function () {
      console.log("my id is: " + p2pSocket.peerId)
    })


    p2pSocket.on('peer-msg', function (data) {
      console.log(data)
    })
```

server side code

```
    var http = require('http')
    var httpServer = http.createServer(requestHandler)
    var fs = require('fs')
    var io = require('socket.io')(httpServer)
    var p2pServerModule = require('socket.io-p2p-server')
    var p2p = p2pServerModule.Server
    var connectedUsers = p2pServerModule.clients
    io.use(p2p)

    httpServer.listen(8000, 'localhost');

    function serveUpFile(req, res, path) {
      fs.readFile(path.toString(), function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          res.writeHead(500);
          return res.end('Error loading index.html');
        }

        res.writeHead(200)
        res.end(data)
      })
    }

    function requestHandler (req, res) {
      if (req.url === '/static/bundle.js') {
        serveUpFile(req, res, './static/bundle.js')
      } else {
        serveUpFile(req, res, './index.html')
      }
    }


    io.on('connection', function (client) {
      console.log('client connected to the server')

      client.on('peer-msg', function (data) {
        console.log('Message from peer %s', data)
      })

      client.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('client disconnected from the server')
      })
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

socket.io-p2p-server will not work with socket.io 1.x as expected.

Change socket.io-p2p-server/index.js:
This part:

```
if (typeof room === 'object') {
  var connectedClients = socket.adapter.rooms[room.name]
} else {
  var connectedClients = clients
}
```

To this:

```
if (typeof room === 'object' && ('name' in room) && (room.name in socket.adapter.rooms) ) {
    var connectedClients = {}
    for (var id in socket.adapter.rooms[room.name].sockets) { 
      connectedClients[id] = clients[id];
    }
} else {
    var connectedClients = clients;
}
```

This solution works for me.